# How do you exit only a pygame window and not the whole code?

Tags: tkinter, pygame, python-3.9

My program doesn't only use Pygame, but also Tkinter, so I have a tkinter window running while the pygame window is. It is common practice that in Pygame code you do `sys.exit()` to stop the `pygame.error: video system not initialized` error, take the code snippet below for example. The problem with this is that if you aren't only running pygame code, this "solution" would be stopping everything in the code instead of just the pygame window. (FYI, this error does not make the program crash or stop, so it's only a console thing, but it's still annoying anyways).

```
import pygame, sys
  
while True:  # event loop
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        pygame.display.update()
```

So, are there any alternatives to `sys.exit()` that only exit the pygame code?

Comment: There is no "after the while loop", that's an infinite `while True:` (which is its own problem, of course, never use a while-true)

Comment: @Mike can't you stop an infinite loop with `break`?

Comment: @danielshmaniel A `break` in the event loop will only break the inner `for` loop, but not the outer `while` loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`sys.exit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit) terminates the interpreter. [`pygame.quit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.quit) uninitialize all pygame modules. Once you have called `pygame.quit()`, calling any other pygame statement will cause an exception. Call `pygame.quit()` after the application loop and remove `sys.exit()`:

```py
run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    # [...]
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: The pygame exiting works for me, but for some strange reason, since I withdrawed the tkinter window before, when I do `root.update() root.deiconify()` after `pygame.quit()` the tkinter window icon appears for a split second and then the python program is nowhere to be seen, not even task manager, even though my editor (PyCharm) tells me it is still running.